# Wordpress site merges

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm not big on Wordpress, so I might have taken a much bigger task than I initially assumed.
So I have a website, that has been cloned last October and has been since updated with a new theme ( Uncode ). Now I want to merge the new website into the old one ( I think it's better that way but I might be wrong ) but since uncode has content blocks that work with IDs, when I try to import the uncodetype posts they will of course have newer IDs than they used to.
In tun this means that the pages that are using said blocks/IDs won't work anymore.

I'm hoping someone had this issue before and knows how to go around it, or even point me towards a tool that can actually handle this gracefully.

Appreciate any help

Comment: It's not really clear what you mean by "merge" in this case. But remember that Wordpress has built-in export/import functions for contents, so you probably can just export the desired content from one site and import it into the other one. The thing you have to be careful about is to install/set up all plugins or custom post types that contained the exported contents also in the other site, otherwise WP won't now what to do with the contents which originates from custom post types.

Answer (score 0):

Posts and other content in newer WordPress installations are likely to use features (related to the newer Gutenberg editor) that aren't present in older installations.  If you want a single site that contains the union of the content in your new and old sites, your best bet is to load your desired content from the old site into the new site.

To do this, you need to figure out which content needs to migrate from the old to the new site. This should be anything that's changed since you cloned the old site to make the new site. There's no need to migrate the unchanged stuff, because it should already be on the new site.

To find the changed stuff, you'll look in your dashboard's All Posts and All Pages displays. But first you need to install the [Admin Columns plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/codepress-admin-columns/). The free version should work.  Then, use that plugin to display the modified date in your All Posts and All Pages displays.

Then, sort your posts and pages by modified date, and use Bulk Edit to add a category (maybe name it NeedsMigrating) to the posts and pages you want to migrate.

Then, use Tools / Export to export just the NeedsMigrating category you just created.

Then, import the exported file into the new site.  You may end up with some duplicate posts to delete.

Comment: Classic editor plugin would be helpful to keep the old posts editable in the way they were created.